# Html5QrcodeScanner can not open the camera on any browser on iphone

Tags: javascript, barcode-scanner

I implemented the Html5QrcodeScanner library in a search field. User can scan a barcode or QR Code and after the scanning is successful, it closes the modal window and pass the value to the fild and search for it. It works fine on Windows, Linux and Android on different browsers, but when I want to use it on iphone and any browser on iphone it opens the camera window, after the scanning is successful it passes the value to the  search field and closes the modal window, until now is everything ok, but when I click or touch the barcode button again to open the modal window and scan other Barcode, modal windows appears but the camera box is not showen, but browser shows the camera symbol, that the browser is using the camera, but there is no camera box to scan. I have to refresh the page to be able to scan again.

Can someone please help me ?